# Issue with takari lifecycle maven plugin downloading maven versions

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

Having an issue running the takari maven plugin to test my custom maven plugin.

For each version I specify, I get an error like this (with only the version changing):

```
java.lang.Exception: Could not resolve maven version 3.5.0
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenJUnitTestRunner$1.error(MavenJUnitTestRunner.java:129)
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.resolve(MavenVersionResolver.java:63)
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenJUnitTestRunner.getRunners(MavenJUnitTestRunner.java:131)
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenJUnitTestRunner.<init>(MavenJUnitTestRunner.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not download maven version 3.5.0 from any configured repository
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.createMavenInstallation(MavenVersionResolver.java:178)
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.resolve(MavenVersionResolver.java:61)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTP/401 Unauthorized
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.openStream(MavenVersionResolver.java:207)
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.createMavenInstallation(MavenVersionResolver.java:161)
    ... 25 more
```

I feel like I have to be missing something.  I haven't seen anything in the takari-lifecycle-plugin docs on configuring credentials for downloading the jars - anyone have suggestions? Note we're using a custom artifactory maven repo in our settings.xml if that makes a difference.

---

EDIT:  Answers that don't deal specifically with configuring the takari plugin aren't really helpful, I know what a HTTP 401 is

Answer (score -1):

error `HTTP/401 Unauthorized` is occur because the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource. and you are using custom artifactory maven so you are specify the repository url, you need to check there url and also use proper authentication credentials with it. check your s`ettings.xml` and `pom.xml`

Comment: I don't see anything in the takari docs on how to configure the repository credentials, do you have an example?